# Would a for loop over an empty list actually spend time / resources?

Tags: python, for-loop, resources

This isn't really a question specific to any code, nor is it an issue I'm having, but for the sake of knowledge I'd like to know.

Say, I have the following code:

```
# list1 and list2 are determinied off the screen
if len(list1) > 0:
    cycler = list1
elif len(list2) > 1:
    cycler = list2
else:
    cycler = []

for id in cycler:
    t = Thing._by_id(id)
    # a lot of stuff done with t
```

In the third occasion, where `cycler = []`, are any resources / time spent with the for loop, or does the for loop break immediately? I'm not worried about this at all, in fact, I have this inside a function and it `return`s in the else clause, I'm just curious.

Comment: the `for` uses the iteration protocol. The list's `__iter__` method is called, which returns an iterator. `id` gets the value returned by `iterator.__next__()`, which raises `StopIteration` as soon as it reaches the end of the list, i.e. on the first call

Answer (score 1):

Not my code, but if we look here, we see that time is used to create this "empty list".

```
% python -mtimeit  "l=[]"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0711 usec per loop

% python -mtimeit  "l=list()"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.297 usec per loop
```

As far as actually iterating through the list, yes, this costs resources as well. The interpretter has to at least know that the list is empty, so it must go into the memory location to see that it is empty.

Comment: Thanks for `-m timeit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if the Python interpreter is able to optimize by skipping the loop entirely, I think the answer is no. If you look at bytecode for iteration over an empty list, all the loop setup steps are still done and bytecode is generated for the code inside the loop (although it won't actually be executed):

```
import dis

def run_empty_loop():
    a = []
    for item in a:
        x = 1 + 1


dis.dis(run_empty_loop)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 29)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (item)

  4          19 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             22 STORE_FAST               2 (x)
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 POP_BLOCK
        >>   29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```